# Binding Form Closing event in class

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

Hello I'm trying to make a class that can handle the form closing event for my winForm

I have figured out how to work the event handlers, like this for a ContextMenuStrip items click event:

```
mnuItemShow.Click += new EventHandler(mnuItemShow_Click);
private void mnuItemShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

But I can't figure out how to bind the Form Closing event..

I have tried it like this:

```
this.form.FormClosing += new EventHandler(closing);
private override void closing(EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

But I get this error message:

> No overload for 'closing' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: Just an unrelated note: In C#, methods usually start with capital letters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be like this:

```
private void closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{

}
```

and you have to add handler like below

```
 frm.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler();
```